# Google Sheets, Querying Filtered Data Row

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Sheet (`KWTT`)- In which, the data is filtered using the default filter view. And, On an another sheet from the same document, I am trying to call part of the filtered information. However, It is pulling the absolute row information, not the filtered information.

```
=KWTT!A3
```

This is the formula that I am using on the second sheet to retrieve data from the first sheet (`KWTT`). However, When I use the  default filter view, the top row swaps to `A121`.

[image: How do I always retrieve the top row of the filtered data in the first sheet to the second sheet?]

How do I always retrieve  the top row of the filtered data in the first sheet to the second sheet?

Comment: You would need a Google apps script

Comment: @anonymous I appreciate the feedback, but that doesn't help me solve the issue. I'm looking for education, not the obvious.

Comment: Obviously I did not provide it as a solution, but as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a lot of trouble, but this will do it. You will probably need to change the ssID and sheet names.

```
function copyFilteredData1Row() {
  var hiddenRows = [];//A 1d array of hidden rows.
  var ssId="1u94OL_HMszOkvvyXdci-SEq7NO0KUJiD1t0xUqHvCMw"//Spreadsheet ID
  var sheetId="0" //Sheet ID
  // limit what's returned from the API
  var fields = 
"sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByFilter)),properties/sheetId)";
  var sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {fields: fields}).sheets;  
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
       if (sheets[i].properties.sheetId == sheetId) {
          var data = sheets[i].data;
          var rows = data[0].rowMetadata;
      for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
          if (rows[j].hiddenByFilter) hiddenRows.push(j)}
    }}

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")//filtered sheet
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")//Copy to sheet
  var lr1=s1.getLastRow()
  var lc1=s1.getLastColumn()
  var lr=s.getLastRow()
  var lc=s.getLastColumn()
  var data1=s.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).getValues()//get all data from filtered sheet.

  var nonHiddenRows=[]//Array of non hidden data.

    for (var i = 1; i <data1.length ; i++) {
    var count=0
    var row = i
    for(var k=0;k<hiddenRows.length;k++){
      var hrow=hiddenRows[k]
    if(row!=hrow){
      count=count+1}
    } 
      if(count==hiddenRows.length){
        nonHiddenRows.push(data1[i])
      if(nonHiddenRows.length==1){break}
      }
    }
  if(s1.getRange(1, 1, 1, 1).getValue()!=""){s1.getRange(1, 1, lr1, 
lc1).clearContent()}//Clear old filtered data.
  s1.getRange(1, 1, nonHiddenRows.length, 
nonHiddenRows[0].length).setValues(nonHiddenRows)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Someone might come up with a js solution. But, Here's a Roundabout formula one with a helper column to find the ***top row only***. It maybe possible to find other filtered rows in the same way. But I am not going to explain all that here, Since the OP was explicit in the top row and uses only `A3` in his original formula second sheet, denoting a single entry.

The helper column J1 in KWTT:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(J1:J1000))
```

In sheet 2

```
  =Indirect ("KWTT!A:"&SUBTOTAL(105,KWTT!J1:J1000))
```

We're using `SUBTOTAL` which skips filtered rows to get a minimum of the visible range and this will be fed into `INDIRECT`.

The whole row can be brought by:

```
 =INDEX(KWTT!A1:I1000,SUBTOTAL(105,KWTT!J1:J1000))
```

However, This set up is still weak on so many grounds. I would rather prefer `FILTER` or `QUERY` to directly filter the array given.

```
 =QUERY(KWTT!A1:I1000,"Select * where A contains 'anime'",1)
```